# Como passar comandos a um .exe via C#?

Tags: c#, parâmetros

Queria chamar através de uma aplicação em C# um *.exe* qualquer e passar a eles alguns comandos assim que abrisse. Por exemplo, o que quero fazer no momento é que o programa abra, dê três <kbd>Tabs</kbd> e preencha com os valores passados e dê mais três <kbd>Tabs</kbd>.

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isto com C#?

Segue o que tentei:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process processo = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\VICTOR\Desktop\Test.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "\t \t \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t 0 \t \t \t";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Ok, agradeço a dica. Aguardarei mais para marcar como resposta nas próximas perguntas. E a resposta que marquei acabou solucionando a pergunta inicial que eu fiz. Para o outro problema, caso eu não consiga resolver, acredito que é melhor fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Correto! Eu ia mesmo sugerir você fazer uma nova pergunta. Eu quis te dar um toque pois notei que você editou a pergunta para torná-la mais intuitiva; mas você já tá ligado. Boa sorte aí!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

Primeiro importe a função `SetForegroundWindow` da `user32.dll` na sua classe:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
```

E pra mandar as teclas você usa `SendKeys`

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process processo;

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.FileName = @"c:\Windows\notepad.exe";

    // inicia o processo
    processo = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    // aguarda até que o processo esteja pronto para receber entrada
    processo.WaitForInputIdle();
    // traz a janela principal pro primeiro plano
    SetForegroundWindow(processo.MainWindowHandle);

    // envia as teclas pro programa
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB 3}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB 3}");
```

A documentação completa da classe `SendKeys` pode ser vista [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui fazer o que queria com isto. Tenho outra dúvida, se puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Como eu pego uma janela secundária aberto pelo programa que está recebendo os comandos para que ela também os receba?

Comment: @VictorMelias Pra isso você pode usar [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Aqui não tens a resposta completa mas um pontapé inicial.

As entradas do usuário (que você quer simular) são enviadas para um formulário (na prática, uma janela do Windows que contém muitas outras janelas) através de um mecanismo chamado **"mensagens do Windows"**.

O Windows oferece uma API para você enviar estas mensagens: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx.

O **C#** não tem uma abstração desta API, de modo que você terá que usá-la diretamente como API do Windows mesmo. [Neste exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523463/1274092), o cidadão envia mensagens de um aplicativo C# para o Notepad (faz o aplicativo escrever texto no notepad).

Basicamente, você tem que localizar o processo do outro aplicativo, identificar neste outro processo o *handle* da janela ("formulário") para a qual você quer enviar as mensagens, e daí enviar as mensagens.

Comment: Ajudou bastante esta explicação. Consegui fazer como o exemplo de mandar um texto pro bloco de notas, mas pelo que consegui entender isso apenas manda texto e não comandos. Não achei uma maneira de alterar o código pra mandar comandos no lugar de texto, como o SendKeys.

Comment: @VictorMelias O segundo parâmetro de SendMessage é o tipo de mensagem que você quer enviar. Alternando este segundo parâmetro você consegue enviar qualquer tipo de mensagem do Windows (como clique de mouse, tecla de atalho, ordem de repintura de janela), inclusive enviar um **Tab**. Eu colocaria um exemplo mas pelo viso o SendKeys já resolveu teu problema. Lembre-se que o SendKeys só envia teclas para a aplicação selecionada em primeiro plano enquanto SendMessage envia para qualquer janela. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: Entendi, obrigado! Na verdade, este é o problema que estou enfrentando agora, enviar comandos para uma segunda janela aberta pelo programa. No link que você passou, eles indicam os parâmetros que podem ser usados aqui http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#system_defined mas não passam o correspondente em hexadecimal. Você sabe onde posso encontrar a lista dos parâmetros em hexadecimal?

Comment: @VictorMelias Eu achei aqui uma lista de constantes: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86987753-eb91-4c13-b0a0-7151778913e4/sendmessage. Então pelo jeito, para enviar um Tab, fica assim: `SendMessage(child, 0x100, 0, 0x09);` - o segundo parâmetro é o tipo da mensagem (key down) e o último é a tecla Tab.

Comment: Agradeço novamente. Infelizmente não deu certo. Nem o Tab (0x09) ou o Enter (0x0D) funcionaram. Vou continuar pesquisando para encontrar uma solução. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @VictorMelias Eu não tenho .Net aqui senão podia fazer uns testes. Se você quer os tabs apenas para posicionar em um determinado controle, experimente enviar mensagem de "set focus".